# Login fail - SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'visitantere'

Tags: php, sql-server, database

Trying to connect my sql server connection with my PHP application, this issue

> SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'visitantere'

appeared.

When I try connect it in dbeaver or ssms, it works fine.

I use PHP 7.2

PHP code:

```
<?php

$user = "usrpostgres";
$password = "P0stgres";

try{
    /*//banco de dados do sace
    $connection = new PDO('pgsql:host=10.16.2.62;port=5432;dbname=cprm_sace_mundau', $user, $password);

    //banco de dados novo para hecdss
    $mundau_hec = new PDO('pgsql:host=10.16.2.62;port=5432;dbname=cprm_sace_mundau_hec', $user, $password);*/

    //banco de dados Sql Server do sace
    $connection = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=SERVRHN-RE\SQLEXPRESS;Database=jdbc:BANCO_HIDRO_SUREG_RE', 'login', 'password');
    $connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

} catch (PDOException $erro){

    echo $erro->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: Posting the code that you are having a problem with would be beneficial...

Comment: oh sorry. Thanks for the advise.

Comment: make sure the password for the user "visitantere" is correct

Comment: I would recommend against posting usernames and passwords in SO

Comment: Thanks for the advise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JDBC is for using SQL Server drivers in Java. Take "jdbc:" out of your connection string:

```
$connection = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=SERVRHN-RE\SQLEXPRESS;Database=BANCO_HIDRO_SUREG_RE', 'visitantere', 'cprm#123*');
```

Comment: Aweasome! Works fine now! Thanks :)

Comment: Great, glad to help!